# List of list extraction based on maximum length

Tags: python-2.7

I have two list of lists in which I need to pick up the element with bigger set of exclusive group. For example, in the below lists,

```
L1 = [['A','B']]
L2 = [['A','B','C','D'],['A','B','E'],['B','E','F'],['A','G']]
```

In `L1, L2[0] & L2[1]` will not qualify because both has `'A'` & `'B'`. This leaves `L2[2:3]`. In this `'B'` is the winner as it is a part of larger group. i.e `set(L2[3])` is 3, but `set(L2[2])` is 2.

Hence, my final output will be `['B']`

I wrote a code (which is working fine for two values) as shown in the following:

```
tmp = []; leng =[]
for i,j in L1: # (i,j allows for only two values)
    for k in L2:
        if i in k and j in k:
            pass
        else:
            tmp.append(k)
            leng.append(len(k))
print tmp;  print leng

for i, j in L1:
    for k in tmp:
        if i in k and len(k) > j in k and len(k) :
            print "Value in if", i
            break
        else:
            print "Value in else", j
            break
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative pythonic way ? 
How should I modify `for i,j in L1:` to accomodate more list of list elements and variable length of each elements ?

Thanks in Advance.

AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L1 = [['A','B'],['C','D','A']]
L2 = [['A','B','C','D'],['A','B','E'],['B','E','F'],['A','G'],['D','E','F','G']]
tmp = []; leng =[]
final_list=[]
for u in L1:
    for k in L2:
        if all(x in k for x in u):
            pass
        else:
            tmp.append(k)
            leng.append(len(k))
    ud = sorted([list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in tmp)],key=len,reverse=True)
    print ud
    winner=[]
    for y in ud:
        for z in u: 
            for o in y:
                if o==z:
                    winner.append(o)
    final_list.append(winner[0])
print "Winners are: ",final_list
```

Result is like

```
 [['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
 winning order
 B
 A
 [['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
 winning order
 D
 A
 A
```

Modified code Result:

```
[['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
Winner in list ['A', 'B'] is : B
[['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
Winner in list ['C', 'D', 'A'] is : D
```

2nd Modified Result:

```
Winners are: ['B', 'D']
```

Note: You can modify your output to get only first result.

Comment: Hi, Great solution. But I will modify it to pick only the element that has max len in other list. i.e B & D.

Comment: @Arun Good. Keep coding. :)

Comment: Objective is to pick B out of [A,B], & D out of [C,D,A] as they have maximum number of unique set list. I tried storing it in a new list, but unable to do it. I think it is because of second for loop. If you look at my code, it considers both presence & length !. How to include length information in second for loop ?

Comment: @Arun ud is the list which sorted in reverse, by length and made unique. (`ud = sorted([list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in tmp)],key=len,reverse=True)` ) Loop works in descending order, checking the presence of ['A','B'] in ud=[['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]. ud[0] dont have A or B. ud[1] has B , ud[2] has A. So winning order is B,A. Here i didnt use the numbers as in yours. But in logical sorted by length only.  if you want just winner alone, include empty list after print ud and append 'o' to it from loop. Print first element of the winner list at the end.

Comment: I tried it already. When I append it appends all of them and when I pick first element i.e o[0] it will give only B. I guess I have to make a list of list for each u. right?

Comment: Hi, As I mentioned in previous comment, it still gives the same result. It prints out the winner but when I try to store it, the final list has only the latest element. I inserted, pickup.append(winner[0]) after your "print "Winner in list {} is :".format(u),winner[0]" and printed the pickup line outside all the loops. The output I get is "Final value in pickup: ['D']"

Comment: @Arun What do you try to achieve? winner of all lists in a list? If yes, then make one more list. If you try winner[0] after all loop finished. you will get only the winner of last list in L1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124277/discussion-between-arun-and-siva-shanmugam).